# remove all newlines not working java (as shown in emacs)

Tags: java, emacs, newline

I have a file which I load in emacs in Fundamental mode.  (The suffix, to be safe, is qqqrrrzzz, so Emacs doesn't set it to text mode and add linewraps.)  I turn on whitespace-mode, and there are a lot of $, showing newlines.

I then run this java code:

```
    out = out.replaceAll("(m?:\\R)", " ");

    out = out.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");

    out = out.replace("\u0085", " ");
    out = out.replace("\u0085", " ");
    out = out.replace("\u2029", " ");

    out = out.replaceAll("\\u0085", " ");
    out = out.replaceAll("\\u2028", " ");
    out = out.replaceAll("\\u2029", " ");

    out = out.replaceAll("\\R", " ");
    out = out.replaceAll("(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)", " ");
    out = out.replace("\r\n", " ");
    out = out.replace("\r", " ");
    out = out.replace("\n", " ");
    out = out.replaceAll("\\r\\n", " ");
    out = out.replaceAll("\\r", " ");
    out = out.replaceAll("\\n", " ");

    out = out.replace("a", "b")
```

(The last bit is just to make sure I'm touching the file.)

And yet the $ at the end of lots of lines in the emacs file persist--the file has not become one big long line, as it should have.

Note that I *CAN* do within emacs "M-x query-replace-regex C-q C-j RET SPACE RET !" and voila in the file everything is one long line.  And yet nothing in java seems to work. :(

I turn on auto-revert-mode, by the way, or manually reload the file in emacs, etc., and I'm sure it's being adjusted, because other adjustments are made via replaceAll.  But no long-line-ification.

Perplexed in Punxatawny,

Phil

(all the above java lines remind me slightly of all the AT-ATs firing at Luke in the end of Last Jedi...)

Comment: As a warning to everyone who is as stupid as me: if you use a BufferedReader, and read in line by line, and adjust each line with the above code, and then write out the adjusted line  ...... your BufferedWriter will write newlines when lines are adjusted to be zero length by the above Last Jedi code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replacing all non-expected newlines, as there are a lot of newline types:

```
out = out.replaceAll("[\\v&&[^\\n\\r]]", "");
```

This replaces all \v (Vertical whitespaces) minus the expected ones.

You might also want to take a look at the following class, which is fundamental to all regex-based operations in standard-Java.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

The doc explicitly states, that \v is not supported, but I have used this, and it does. :)